# Finding a (null) related item when there shouldn't be any related

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm working on my first CakePHP project. In my baked view for "Item", there is a "related" div which shows "Related Projects".

It checks if the 'Project' array is empty:

```
<div class="related">
    <h3><?php echo __('Related Projects'); ?></h3>
<?php if (!empty($item['Project'])): ?>
    <dl>
      ...
```

Seeing as the 'projects' db table is empty right now, I would think this would be empty. However, I'm getting this in `$item['Project']`:

```
["Project"]=> array(7) { 
    ["id"]=> NULL 
    ["item_id"]=> NULL
    ["title"]=> NULL
    ...
}
```

I could work around this by checking for a NULL id, but I want to avoid work-arounds and do things the Cake way.

**Controller:**

```
public function view($id = null) {
    if (!$this->Item->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid item'));
    }
    $options = array('conditions' => array('Item.' . $this->Item->primaryKey => $id));
    $this->set('item', $this->Item->find('first', $options));
}
```

**Model:**

```
public $hasOne = array(
    'Project' => array(
        'className' => 'Project',
        'foreignKey' => 'item_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is normal when doing $hasOne and therefore direct left joins.
It will populate those related fields with null values - just as mysql would, as well.

Check on the id of that record then:

```
if (!empty($item['Project']['id']) {}
```

Comment: Thanks for that information. Is there any way to have it not populate unless there is a match? Would it make sense to change it to $hasMany even though it will only ever have one or none?

Comment: No, it would not make sense. I already gave you the answer. Either the whole record is an empty array (if there is no primary record) or you need to use the above check.